# Use Powershell with Azure to retrieve the ConnectionString of an AuthoriztionRule of a Service Bus Topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-powershell, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm a bit of an Azure & Powershell newbie.

I'm trying to write PowerShell scripts to create an environment that can be published to from Azure DevOps.

As part of that, I'm creating a Service Bus with multiple topics. Each of the topics will have multiple Authorization Rules - one for publication and one for subscription.

I have the scripts for this working. However, I need to get the connection strings for these rules and save them to a key vault, to make them available to apps.

This is where I have become stuck.

This is similar to my existing code:

```
   New-AzServiceBusTopic -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Namespace myServiceBus -EnablePartitioning $false -Name myTopic

   New-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule `
      -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `
      -Namespace myServiceBus `
      -Topic myTopic`
      -Name myTopic.pub  `
      -Rights  @("Send")
```

In the Azure Portal, I would click into the Service bus and Topic, select Shared Access Policies and click on the policy. It would show me the SAS Policy with the Primary Connection String.

Is there any way in PowerShell to get the Primary Connection String?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this, maybe this is what you are looking for: Get-AzServiceBusKey

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/get-azservicebuskey?view=azps-5.1.0

Comment: This was exactly what I was after, and spent the best part of an afternoon failing to find. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have azure powershell `Az.ServiceBus` module installed, you can directly use this command: [Get-AzServiceBusKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/get-azservicebuskey?view=azps-5.1.0).

For example:

```
Get-AzServiceBusKey -ResourceGroup Default-ServiceBus-WestUS -Namespace SB-Example1 -Name AuthoRule1
```